# Running a loop using Logistic Regression

Tags: loops, regression

I have 3 datasets I'd like to run a logistic regression on split into

X1, y1
X2, y2
X3, y3

How can I run a loop so that I can run an automated logistic regression using the X_train, X_test split function from Sklearn and in doing so printing 3 separate accuracy results for each dataset?

To run on one data set of X, y is as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.25, shuffle=False)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)

print('Accuracy:',metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: Would you please post a small example data set?

Comment: X: array([[ 0.01569122,  0.02144745,  0.02732686, ...,  0.92322002,
         0.184644  ,  0.30327971],
       [ 0.89029458,  0.01569122,  0.02144745, ...,  0.95034668,
         0.19006934,  0.20071533],    Y: array([[ 1.],
       [-1.],
       [-1.],
       ...,
       [ 1.],
       [-1.],
       [ 1.]])

Comment: My apology, I meant add the data to your question so that it is not truncated.

Comment: The arrays are very large, the y array is just a list of 1s and -1s, for X you can generate an array of random numbers if needed so that it's of shape (2372, 8)